# Determination of the operational space dynamic model (Task space)

Tags: dynamics

I am trying to implement a **hybrid Force/Motion controller** for a quadruped. To do that I first need the **Inverse Dynamic Model** of the robot in **Operational Space**.

I found a lot of resources on how to create the controller but I cannot find any algorithm to compute the **Inverse Dynamic Model** of the robot in **Operational Space**. 
Can you point me to some articles or books ?

Cheers,
Titouan